# How to design a leaderboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, leaderboards

This sounds like an easy thing but when I considering the following

- Many players
- Some have played many games and some just started
- Different type of statistics

On what information should the actual ranking be based on? I am planning to display the board in a UITableView so there is limited space available per player. However, I am not bound to the UITableView if there is a better solution.

This is a quiz game and the information I am currently capturing per player is:

- #games played totally
- #games played per game type (current version have only one game type)
- #questions answered
- #correct answers

Maybe I should include additional information.

I have been thinking about having a leaderboard property page where the player can decide on what basis the leaderboard should display information but would like to avoid the complexity in that. However, if that is needed I will do it.

Anyone that can give me some advice on how to design the presentation of this would be highly appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as leader board development you can get it from the gamekit

check out this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjF82OYGBq4&feature=player_embedded

as far as the artistic design that really depends on style of you game.

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for that Abe, very interesting. However i am not planning to use Game center in this game but rather add a view with the result for only this particular phone.

Comment: i see what you mean then a table view does almost seem like over kill. otherwise laying it out would be a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 1):

You could base the ranking on a "weighted" average. For instance, the number of games played would have a smaller weight in the average compared to the number of correct answers. That way you provide a general ranking based on different information.
It's also a nice "feature" for the user to be able to look at rankings according to specific info.