# Design leaderboard ratings for quiz games

Tags: objective-c, game-center

Back in March 2011 i started the following post: [How to design a leaderboard?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9250/how-to-design-a-leaderboard)

Now my quiz game have been out for approximately a year and sold pretty decently. I am working on to update the game design and is again looking into the leaderboard design to make it better as i am not happy with it.

Currently i rate players on number of correct answers, which is not good as it does not consider things like number of games, difficulty levels etc. I also have "extended" stats behind the UITableView (Leaderboard).

- A player can play based on three levels of difficulty: hard, medium or easy
- Difficulty levels can be mixed between players in a game
- Each game can be one to six players, so there can be single games or duels
- Between 2 and 30 questions per game

As i am considering integrating Game Center Leaderboard i need to design a better rating system so i would like to ask for some ideas how to do the rating based on the above.

I am thinking about how much a point would be worth and what it includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few ideas:

- Create a separate leaderboard for each difficulty level.
- You might also want to consider having second set of leaderboards which auto reset say once a month.
- I'd be tempted to use something like an [Elo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) system for ranking. That is you start with a fixed number of points, and gain or lose a variable number of points based on the difficulty of your opponents. Maybe with the maximum point gain/loss based on the question count.
- Using the Elo system would require a different design for the single player leaderboard, so that would need to be separate too. How about 1000*(correct answers/(incorrect answers + K)) where K is there to limit the maximum score for people who've only answered a few questions. You could apply results from multiplayer games to the single player leaderboards if you want to.